# Sending message from ActiveMQ Classic to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Classic in this configuration:

```
client/producer -> ActiveMQ Classic -> ActiveMQ Classic
```

I need to change it to:

```
client/producer -> ActiveMQ Classic -> ActiveMQ Artemis
```

The connection between Classic and Artemis has been established, but Artemis is not visible as consumer on Classic on web console.

Network connector is bad?

How change consumer from Classic to Artemis?

Comment: You need to provide far more details here as there just isn't anything for anyone to look at and see what you are really doing.  Try to formulate a problem statement that clearly sums up what you are trying to accomplish and what isn't working, then add configuration details and any other debugging data you've collected.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current configuration on my amq server (amqhost1) which is producer for another amq server (amqhost2). A need change configuration and replace amqhost2 with artemis:

```
    <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector
                            name="amqhost1->amqhost2"
                            uri="static:(tcp://amqhost2_IP:61616)"
                            duplex="false"
                            decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                            networkTTL="2"
                            dynamicOnly="true">
                    <excludedDestinations>
                            <topic physicalName=">" />
                    </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
    </networkConnectors>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure ActiveMQ Artemis
2. Configure ActiveMQ Classic
3. Define Connection Factory
4. Send Message

Comment: This is incredibly broad advice. Why would this solve the problem? Can you [edit] your answer to provide more detail?